# Is it possible to perform a computation to know if an object is at rest and its location given a force versus position diagram?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

The problem is as follows:

> The force graphed in Figure 1. is applied to a $\textrm{2.0-kg}$
>   block that was sliding to the right (the $\textrm{+-direction}$) over
>   a frictionless surface with speed $5.0\,\frac{m}{s}$ at $x=0$ (a) Is
>   the block ever at rest? If so,where? (b) Find a position (other than
>   $x=0$) when the block is again moving to the right at
>   $5.0\,\frac{m}{s}$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The figure alluded in the problem is shown above.

Now the thing with this problem is I really don't know where to begin or if there is something missing in my maths.

Hence my question is how do I know that the block is at rest?.

My first guess is that this happens when the net force on the block is $0$ or that it is not carrying (unsure if this term is right) kinetic energy?. However can this happen in a frictionless surface?. My other question arises from the fact, how do I understand the negative force in the diagram?. Does it mean that is a force that is being applied to the left side of the block?.

So far the only thing I could come up with wad to use Newton's second law:

$f=ma$

Since what it is being asked is the position, I thought to use:

$v^{2}_f=v^{2}_{0}+2a\Delta x$

For  $v^{2}_f=0$ and $v_{0}=5\,\frac{m}{s}$,

$0=\left(5\right)^{2}_{0}+2a\Delta x$

But this would mean to use a, from where? From the diagram?.

If so, at $-40 N$ :

$a=\frac{-40}{2}=-20\,\frac{m}{s^2}$

Then:

$0=\left(5\right)^{2}+2\left(-20\right)\Delta x$

Hence:

$\Delta x=\frac{25}{40}=0.625$

Which would translate as a position $x=0$

$x_{1}-x_{0}=0.625-0=0.625\,m$

So this would be at the right from the starting point at $x=0$ and although this seems consistent with what it is alluded in the diagram (the "domain" is in the positive numbers) it doesn't check with the answers in my book.

According to it, the answer for part (a) is $1\,\textrm{m}$ and for part (b) is $2.917\,\textrm{m}$. But again, none of this seems close to what I obtained. What could I be missing in my calculation?.

Anyways. Am I understanding this mathematically or physically wrong?. Can somebody help me to clear these doubts?.

Comment: "the net force on the block is 0 or that it is not carrying (unsure if this term is right) kinetic energy". You know that these are two entirely different phenomenon, right? Net force = 0 does not imply rest.

Comment: @harshit54 I'm so sorry. I'm still new to this field. Mind to enlighten me with what you refer to as "different phenomenon"?. My doubt is, there must be kinetic energy since there is a speed $v_0$ but net force must be zero when it comes at rest?. Am I mixing things up?. Maybe you can help me to clear out these questions.

Comment: No need to be sorry. Rest is implied when the velocity of a particle is zero. Velocity can be found out by taking the integral of the acceleration function with respect to time.

Comment: In your case you just need to calculate the area under the curve from $t= 0$ to some $t=t$ and set it equal to zero. All this is done assuming you start at from rest.

Comment: @harshit54 Thanks! But then the question arises to, what function to use for integration? as I believe there are three intervals in the graph. Just should I try them all?.

Comment: @harshit54 But the graph is force versus position not force versus time. Hence what to integrate?. Would it mean that by doing this is work and not energy what I'm obtaining?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87808/discussion-between-harshit54-and-chris-steinbeck-bell).

Comment: Hint: When working in the distance domain instead of the time domain, applying conservation of energy is often fruitful.

Comment: @amd I thought about this. Does this corresponds to one of the suggested answers?. Because I'm stuck at part b.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Did you understand the area I was talking about? So for this specific case of part b, when v(x=0) = 5m/s to the right then, you just have to find an x integrating to which the area is 0.

Comment: @harshit54 There is some problem displaying equations in chat mode, but I understood that I had to integrate the speed and from it I'll obtain a squared equation which can solve to find position, being $[\frac{v^2}{2}]^{x}_{0}$ since you refer this to as area equal to zero. I was confused at what would be the value of "a". Besides integration will produce a constant. Don't I have to worry about this?.

Comment: [Chat Problem](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-can-i-enable-mathjax-in-chat)

Comment: a is the function that the graph represents divided by 2(the mass).

Comment: @harshit54 I overlooked that part, now it seems obvious!. However this would require to divide by $2$ all the values on $y$ and with that integrate, so that the result equates to zero. Did I understood this part correctly?.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: If the end points and breaks in the force curve as exactly at grid intersections as pictured, then despite what your book says, the solution to part (b) should be exactly 3m.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

You have

$$
m \ddot x = f(x) = \begin{cases}
 5 (6 x-8) & x \le 2 \\
 20 & 2\lt x \le 3 \\
 10 (2 x-4) & x \gt 3 
\end{cases}
$$

then

$$
m\dot x \ddot x = f(x)\dot x\to \frac m2 \frac{d}{dt}\dot x ^2 = \frac{d}{dt}F(x)
$$

then integrating

$$
\frac 12 m (v^2-v_0^2) = F(x) = \begin{cases}
 15 x^2-40 x & x\leq 2 \\
 20 x-60 & 2<x\leq 3 \\
 20 \left(\frac{x^2}{2}-2 x\right)+30 & 3 < x
\end{cases}
$$

Attached the plot for $f(x)$ in blue, the plot for $F(x)$ in red and the plot for $v(x)$ in black showing the points in which $v = v_0$ which occurs at $x = 0$ and $x = 3$

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I was hoping that the answer would rely into precalculus anyways... $v_{0}$ is known so what's with $v$ do what?. $v=0$ and from then on to calculate from $F(x)$ the position, but what $F(x)$ should I use?. Let's say between $[0,2]$ with $F(x)=30x-40$ I obtained $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and again this is not close to the answer. Can you further help? I'm stuck.

Comment: I think in this case a much better help than a plot would be by stating which is the part where I'm stuck on with the calculation. The second graph is I don't understand, does it states explicitly the values of $x$? What's the horizontal line for, to indicate just $25$?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell I hope now helps more.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell The equation you should use is $m\ddot x = f(x)$ with all it's consequences.

Comment: @amd Thanks for the tip.

Comment: So from those three functions states I have to find their roots?. The first one for example would produce $x=0$ and $x=\frac{8}{3}$ if I'm not wrong equating all to zero. I'm not very fond with the dot notation over the $x$. Hence I tagged as precalculus, but do you meant $\frac{dx}{dt}$ for $\dot{x}$? I don't see much purpose of adding $\frac{d}{dt}$ to $F(x)$.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell The block is at rest when $v=0$ This happens at $x = 1$ and $x = \frac 53$ also you should now that $\int_0^t f(x(t))\dot x(t) dt = F(x(t))$

Comment: for this to happen one should use $15x^2-40x+25=0$. Although, I believe **this** should be stated clearly, because what is equated to $F(x)$ represents the work, so more explicitly. $\frac{1}{2}\times 2 \left(0-5^2\right)$. However the problem arises with $x=\frac{5}{3}$ as it is not listed as an answer. Could it be that I misinterpreted something?.

Comment: I'm re-reading at your proposed answer, but I'd like to get a clarification of the notation used, because I'm getting confused with the dot over the $x$. what's the meaning of \dot{x}^2? by going reading the line where this is put, it turns out to be F(x) but why? Can you add this in your answer?. I'm asking this because I'm not very savvy with calculus. What I'm only understanding from that line is that $F=\frac{m}{2}$.

Comment: The first derivative (I suppose the $x$ with the dot on it) is referred to as the speed, but this is with respect of time, however we have a function dependent of position. Does taking the derivative against the position obtains the same?. I'm confused at these steps hence I'd hope you can help me with the theoretical background, because I want to understand what you're doing.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Just a quick note about your pre-calculus request: If you look at the last equation, what you need to notice is that on the left is the change in kinetic energy, and on the right is the work done by the force. $|Delta E_{kinetic}=W$. You can get this work from simple geometry, since it's the area under the curve of the force vs distance. And all you have is triangles and rectangles.

Comment: @Andrei Thanks!. In fact I've realized this, however I wanted to understand better what was the meaning of the dots (in terms of representation) of derivatives. As mentioned above, I thought that the first derivative with respect of time was speed and the second derivative was acceleration. But in this case was done with respect of "length"?, so I don't know what was actually intended to mean, since the functions are in therms of $x$. Moreover why it was chosen to use $\dot{x}$ and $\ddot{x}$ in the line above the integration.

Answer (score 1):

> $v^{2}_f=v^{2}_{0}+2a\Delta x$

That applies when you have constant acceleration. The graph shows that force, and therefore acceleration, is changing. So you can't use this formula.

You have that the horizontal axis (width) is distance, and the vertical (height) is force. Height times width is area, and force times distance is work. So area in this diagram represents work (keep in mind that area below the x-axis is negative work). In general, when you have a diagram where the horizontal has units $a$, and the vertical has units $b$, then area represents something with units $ab$.

You're given that at $x=0$, the velocity is +5. From that, and the mass, you can figure out the initial kinetic energy. For the object to be at rest, the new kinetic energy must be 0, which means that work so far must cancel out the initial kinetic energy. So you need to find a point on the graph such that area to the left of that point is the negative of the initial kinetic energy.

> how do I understand the negative force in the diagram?

A negative force means a force in the "negative" direction. What direction is considered "negative" is somewhat arbitrary, and can be chosen according to what's convenient for the problem. If it's not stated, it's generally assumed that right is positive and left is negative. And indeed, the problem says "the right (the +-direction)", so that tells you that right is the positive direction, and left is the negative direction.

Comment: @Accumulation *So you need to find a point on the graph such that area to the left of that point is the negative of the initial kinetic energy.* So all that I have to do is to relate both works, a work which cancels the other?. Can you do an example?. Sorry but I am still a bit stuck with this one. I mean if kinetic energy performs work, then other kinetic energy will null the effect of the first (work) and this is understood as the block to be at rest?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Work is change in energy. If the initial kinetic energy is $E_0$, then you need to change the energy from $E_0$ to $0$, which is a change of $-E_0$, so you need the work to be equal to that.

Comment: @Accumulation I see, so because the area relates to position (in this graph) from it I could obtain the point from which it nulls that right?. I totally overlooked the fact that acceleration was changing. Still I'm confused what is meant by part b in the question, how do I know that $x=0$ the block is moving to the right, does it mean that passed that point the block will move to the left and then to the right?.

Comment: @Accumulation. By following your hint I obtained an expression like this $\frac{-40-a}{2}b=-25$ being $a$ and $b$ the sides of the trapezoid. But to choose which?. There are countless possibilities from the graph, however if I reduce it to the most visual being the one at $a=F=-20$, then $b=x=\frac{5}{6}$ this doesn't check. Now if I try$a=-10$then$b=1$which correspond to the "answer". However,how about the point passed$x=1$the block moves to the left,negative work. But is part (b) where I'm stuck at now,how to relate it? I thought that it was at$x=1.66\,m$where the area counters the left side

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Why would you choose anything but $a=0$? That’s where the retarding force is first applied, after all.

Comment: @amd $a=0$ would meant there is no upper side in the trapezoid. Will it make sense to calculate its area if $a=0$?. Because of this I didn't choose it.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell A trapezoid that’s missing a side is a triangle.

Comment: @amd In my rushed analysis totally overlooked that part. However by going into that route will make $b=x=1.25$ which doesn't seem to be the "right" answer.

Comment: @amd We don't know for sure that the retarding force started at $x=0$. The reason we should choose $a=0$ is that that's the reference point: we're told (implicitly) what the kinetic energy was at that point, so we should measure how much work has been done since the last know kinetic energy.

Comment: @Acccumulation A fair point, if one is being strict. A distinction without a difference here, I would say.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell You need to measure (signed) areas from the $x$-axis, not from the bottom of the graph.

Comment: @amd Wouldn't it be the same in the end?. However, the reason why I did that was that to find the area of the trapezoid  is easier to relate the lenghts of the bases. I must indicate that letter "$a$" is just an arbitrary letter I used not "acceleration". Since the directions as told by answerer was to find an area to cancel that I equated the initial work $+25\,J$ so that it should cancel with a "negative work" starting from $x=0$ going up to who knows where, therefore which would be the lenght of the upper base?. If had known beforehand that is zero, then can be found $b=x$.

Comment: @amd But again, even following this procedure doesn't seem to be very convincing or maybe I'm not doing it right.

Comment: @amd I'd like to note that going from one route (calculus) or just trapezoid areas (non-calculus) in the end the result seems the same $\frac{\left(-40+30x-40\right)}{2}\left(x\right)=-25$ to which results into $x=1$ and $x=\frac{5}{3}$. But I'm confused at the interpretation of motion, **why** a block moves to the right when a **negative** force is applied and then moves to the left with a **positive** force and again to the right with the same sign force. Is that possible!?. If you could clear this for me I could say my understanding would be better. :)

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell That question is more appropriate for a physics forum, but recall Newton's first law: the block starts the experiment in motion and will happily continue moving rightward absent applied forces. Consider, too, your own experience. When you apply the brakes on your bike or car, the resulting retarding force (and acceleration) is directed backward, yet the vehicle happily continues moving forward for quite some time. A closer analogy is a ball thrown straight upwards in a vacuum (so there’s no air resistance)—the only force on it is downward, but the ball goes upward anyway.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell I’ll also add that you shouldn’t think of the force as “negative.” The sign simply tells you the direction of the force as it does for the velocity here (what’s a “negative velocity?”), just as in two dimensions you’d have an angle that tells you its direction.

Comment: @amd Sorry about the delay in the response. But the analogy which you explained really helped me but not in full. I'm still pondering, if the retarding force applied to the block (which in this case is changing) it will make the block stop. Then the force which is in the opposite direction of the original motion combined with the motion in that **reversed** direction will make the block to increase its speed. But why the **representation** of this in the plot keeps showing motion to the **right**, wouldn't make sense that is represented as going backwards?.

Comment: @amd Then the block which moves to left slows down until stop (as the force is in the other direction), and as previous case. Shouldn't this be represented as not advancing in the $x-axis$ but going backwards? as the other part when the motion resumes to go into the right makes sense that the line goes along the $x-axis$ as it increases. Again sorry if it sounds convoluted but I felt dumbfounded at trying to understand this part.